# Keeping food slow cooking for indefinite periods

Tags: food-safety, slow-cooking

Here's a weird question for the food safety enthusiasts on the forum.

I've just moved into a new apartment without a refrigerator. The landlord has promised to supply one in three weeks - and I don't feel like wasting money on a mini-fridge for such a short period of time.

However - I also don't particularly feel like subsisting on McDonalds until then, so I have thought of a possible solution and wanted to put it to the crowd to weigh in on whether it is safe.

Basically, I've been slow cooking vegetable soup and keeping it on 'low' in the crockpot until the dish has been eaten - then, I repeat the process.

I have done this 4 times already with successful results on each occasion: to my surprise, the dish was still tasty after 3 days, although I was initially nervous about eating something that had been cooking for so long.

I measured the temperature of the food and it remains about 70C the whole time.

So here's my question.

Is this a viable solution until my refrigerator arrives or is there something unsafe about cooking foods for such long periods? Is there an upper limit on how long food can be cooked for and stay good?

TIA for any responses!

Comment: @rumtscho I think this is not a duplicate, the other question is asking about periodically reheating the soup, whereas this one asks about a soup which is constantly kept warm.

Comment: @JohnEye good catch. I knew we have lots of questions along these lines, but picked the wrong target - the new one should be better suited.

Comment: @rumtscho Yeah, that one is better, thanks for linking it. I wonder if there's any possibility of cultivating any extremophile bacteria in such a pot over time, but those would probably be unable to survive at normal temperature. Toxins are another question though, this could possibly be a fascinating scientific paper.